# Windows: django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Error loading MySQLdb module. Did you install mysqlclient?

Tags: python, virtualenv, mysql-connector

In my Windows10 ,

I have installed `mysqlclient` in my `venv` ( I checked the path `venv\Lib\sitepackages` found `mysqlclient-1.4.6.dist-info\`).

however, when I use command to runserver:

```
>python3 manage.py runserver
```

get `Did you install mysqlclient?` error,

details:

```
Watching for file changes with StatReloader
Exception in thread django-main-thread:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Users\80361576\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\mysql\base.py", line 15, in <module>
    import MySQLdb as Database
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'MySQLdb'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Users\80361576\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\threading.py", line 926, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "D:\Users\80361576\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\threading.py", line 870, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "D:\Users\80361576\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 54, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "D:\Users\80361576\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 109,
in inner_run
    autoreload.raise_last_exception()
  File "D:\Users\80361576\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 77, in raise_last_excep
tion
    raise _exception[1]
  File "D:\Users\80361576\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 337, in execute

    autoreload.check_errors(django.setup)()
  File "D:\Users\80361576\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 54, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "D:\Users\80361576\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\__init__.py", line 24, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "D:\Users\80361576\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 114, in populate
    app_config.import_models()
  File "D:\Users\80361576\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\apps\config.py", line 211, in import_models
    self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
  File "D:\Users\80361576\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 728, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "D:\Users\80361576\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\models.py", line 2, in <module>
    from django.contrib.auth.base_user import AbstractBaseUser, BaseUserManager
  File "D:\Users\80361576\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\base_user.py", line 47, in <module>
    class AbstractBaseUser(models.Model):
  File "D:\Users\80361576\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 117, in __new__
    new_class.add_to_class('_meta', Options(meta, app_label))
  File "D:\Users\80361576\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 321, in add_to_class
    value.contribute_to_class(cls, name)
  File "D:\Users\80361576\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\options.py", line 204, in contribute_to_
class
    self.db_table = truncate_name(self.db_table, connection.ops.max_name_length())
  File "D:\Users\80361576\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\__init__.py", line 28, in __getattr__
    return getattr(connections[DEFAULT_DB_ALIAS], item)
  File "D:\Users\80361576\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 201, in __getitem__
    backend = load_backend(db['ENGINE'])
  File "D:\Users\80361576\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 110, in load_backend
    return import_module('%s.base' % backend_name)
  File "D:\Users\80361576\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "D:\Users\80361576\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\mysql\base.py", line 20, in <module>
    ) from err
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Error loading MySQLdb module.
Did you install mysqlclient?
```

environment version:

```
Windows 10
Python 3.7.8
Django 2.2.12
mysqlclient 1.4.6
```

Comment: The paths in your stack trace look like you're not using the python in your virtualenv

Comment: I do activate the venv/Scripts/activate.bat